# eBay Trading API - get out of stock items

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I'm trying to get all my items on eBay that are out of stock.

Right now I'm using the API call `GetMyeBaySelling`, but I can only fetch the current active items.

In [API documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSellingManagerInventory.html) I saw that there is a `GetSellingManagerInventory` call, that I think is the call I need to use.

I tried this call, but I never got any result.

Here is my **request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellingManagerInventoryRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Pagination>
        <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    </Pagination>
    <Sort>ActiveQuantity</Sort>
    <SortOrder>Ascending</SortOrder>
    <MessageID>test</MessageID>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>'.$auth.'</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</GetSellingManagerInventoryRequest>
```

**Response**

```
Array
(
    [Timestamp] => 2013-09-16T18:15:17.535Z
    [Ack] => Success
    [CorrelationID] => test
    [Version] => 841
    [Build] => E841_UNI_API5_16362888_R1
    [InventoryCountLastCalculatedDate] => 2013-09-16T08:56:13.000Z
    [PaginationResult] => Array
        (
            [TotalNumberOfPages] => 0
            [TotalNumberOfEntries] => 0
        )

)
```

So I'm guessing I need to put a `<Search>` like they have documented in the docs and came up with a **new request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellingManagerInventoryRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Search>
    <SearchType>Title</SearchType>
    <SearchValue>2333-XL</SearchValue>
  </Search>
  <Pagination>
    <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
  <Sort>ActiveQuantity</Sort>
  <SortOrder>Ascending</SortOrder>
  <MessageID>test</MessageID>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>'.$auth.'</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</GetSellingManagerInventoryRequest>
```

The response, however, remained the same (note that the search field entered is one listing that I have, so it should give me some result).

So I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetMyeBaySelling** will return the items with stock 0 if you set **OutOfStockControl** to true when listing the item using AddFixedPriceItem. When calling GetMyeBaySelling the **QuantityAvailable** field will not be returned which means the stock level = 0

Comment: Yes this work and that is what I did a while ago. But il mark your awnser as apcepted since that is what I did at the moment of this question.